# Fingerprint login in 20.04

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

I saw an OMG Ubuntu article about Ubuntu offering fingerprint support. But I do not see any such option in 20.04.

Is it really possible to login using fingerprint scan in 20.04? If yes, how?

Comment: Take a look at frpintd, but keep in mind you'll still need a password to unlock your keyring, so not as useful as you might hope.

Comment: Go to users -> Automatic login, and that should display the option for fingerprint login. I can't get mine to work, but if it does work, that's where it'll be

Comment: It works without auto login under user settings. Thanks.

Comment: OP, I have the same question. I have a ThinkPad X1 Carbon with a fingerprint reader that is recognized by 20.04 I have "enrolled" my fingerprint via Settings > Users and "Fingerprint Login" there is marked "Enabled".  But on the login screen there is no visible option to activate fingerprint scanning, and simply trying it does nothing (i.e. password still required). I'm wondering if this is DM related. I upgraded from 19.04 after long use and may not have the stock DM active.

Comment: @PaulBissex I have the same setup but i don't get anything on Settings > Users. Did you get this working?

Comment: @CpILL - I did. I didn't change anything in the config (that I remember). I gave up looking for on-screen indicators; the reader itself has an LED that flashes to say it's active. After realizing that it was a matter of adjusting to how it works -- how many swipes (it's a bar-type reader, not a pad), how fast, how firm I'd say it works reasonably about 85% of the time. Not as good as the fingerprint sign-in on my work-issued MacBook, but passable.

Comment: thanks @PaulBissex but it can't seem to see my fingerprint reader? Which is strange if we have the same machine...? I'll see if i can get the LED to light up. Did you install special drovers for it?

Comment: @CpILL I didn't install any extra drivers, it "just worked" starting with 20.04 for me. Light might not have happened until after I registered a print. 2nd gen X1 Carbon FWIW.

Answer (score 25):

What you need to do is to enable PAM Fingerprint authentication method.

1. Issue `sudo pam-auth-update`
2. Select *Fingerprint authentication*
3. Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This answer solved it for me, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It probably depends on the HW support installed. Did not work for me on my out of the box Dell XPS 15, after I fresh installed ubuntu 20.04

Comment: works for me but after rebooting its disabled again (but showing up ad enabled)

Comment: No work for me on 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 :(

Comment: Some laptops manufacturers have no drivers yet for fingerprint working on linux distributions

Comment: triggering pam-auth-update is last step, one might need to do all steps [few steps from guide for non GNOME remixes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243194/10334)

Comment: Note for those who did not know how to select the Figerprint Authentication USE SPACE BAR to select it

Comment: After hours of searching finally, this one solved my problem. I needed to install fprintd and libpam-fprintd with apt install first.

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved it by upgrading firmware using

```
fwupdmgr upgrade
```

Now I get the option of login using fingerprint in settings->users. And I can get my fingerprints scanned there.

But I still can't really login with it. Nothing happens when I scan my fingers when the computer is locked.

Comment: Just figured it all out by following the answer above.