# Fingerprint GUI not installing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fingerprint-reader, policykit

I'm trying to install fingerprint-gui on my Lenovo Ideapad 520 having Ubuntu 20.04 on which fingerprint isn't working for now.

I tried going directly to Settings → Users → Automatic login and enabled the fingerprint login, but the error is:

> Could not access any fingerprint readers Please contact your system administrator for help!

I also tried to install Fingerprint GUI:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

but encountered this error:

```
E: Package 'policykit-1-fingerprint-gui' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'fingerprint-gui' has no installation candidate
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Thee was never `fingerprint-gui` package in Ubuntu repos. You probably installed it from some PPA.

Comment: Fingerprint GUI is no longer maintained and is not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 and newer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fingerprint GUI is no longer maintained and is not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 and newer. There is a built-in fingerprint login feature in 20.04 under Settings->Users->Authentication & Login.

Comment: sounds awesome. I'll check that when I get to the Laptop where it was a thing, thanks for the info

Comment: I tried going to Settings -> Users -> Automatic login and enable the fingerprint login, But the error is:

Could not access any fingerprint readers Please contact your system administrator for help!

Comment: You may need to add the drivers for that particular reader.

Comment: What about Xubuntu?

Comment: @AlanBrooks , By any chance,  Do you know what drivers do I need for an Asus Laptop for enabling fingerprint scanner?

Comment: It depends on which scanner you're using. If it's built-in, then I'd check the Asus website.

Comment: nothing like fingerprint feature for Lenovo P50 available even in Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: There is no such settings on my Lenovo laptop with built-in fingerprint reader.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and on Lenovo ThinkPad T590. OK.

Answer (score 17):

Follow this guide for non GNOME remixes:

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/fingerprint-login-ubuntu-mate/20852

Fingerprint login setup is available via a GUI for Gnome, however there is no current GUI for Ubuntu MATE.

The following steps will enable Fingerprint Login and user privilege escalation in Ubuntu MATE, please note that some of this will be dependent on the specific laptop you are using.

First step check your laptop for an available fingerprint reader

```
lsusb
```

If you have one listed then please follow the steps few steps:

```
sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

Now you need to enroll your fingerprint:

```
fprintd-enroll
```

Follow the prompt and swipe your right index finger across your scanner 5 times until you get the following: Enroll result: enroll-completed

Now you need to enable access:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

This will open an ncurses interface. Add an * next to Fingerprint authenication and tab over to OK and exit.

At this point you will be able to use your fingerprint scanner to authenticate to elevated privileges, ie. sudo. It will also allow you to login and unlock your system using the fingerprint reader.

This has been tested on Ubuntu MATE 18.04, 19.10, and the current daily 20.04.

(Also I can  confirm Xubuntu 20.04.)

Comment: thanks, I think running pam-auth-update and enabling fingerprint made my Goodix fingerprint reader work on my Dell Inspiron 5482 after following : https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/hq3kf3/xps_13_fingerprint_drivers_are_here/ :)

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 21.04 also, (Pop!_OS).  Thanks, please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) first.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
```

Luckily it already supports `focal`.

Comment: I did add the PPA first, and then I installed libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui. And it gave me this error

Comment: except it kinda doesnt its build for focal is having a dependency wait for libpolkit-qt-1-dev which straight up is as far as I saw not being built for focal.

Answer (score 0):

sudo pam-auth-update

works fine with standard (not tuned) U20.04.2
finally I can confirm sudo actions via fprint reader