# Fingerprint-gui not installing in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, policykit, dell-vostro

I tried the following but no use:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package policykit-1-fingerprint-gui
E: Unable to locate package fingerprint-gui
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fingerprint gui not installing in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231357/fingerprint-gui-not-installing-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their page says the following https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui:

> NOTE: Fingerprint GUI is no longer maintained and is not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 and newer

Comment: Thank you.
Without your response I would keep trying

Comment: is there an alternative to it?