# Fingerprint reader under Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome 3.36?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234823/1187373) that Ubuntu 20.04 was supporting fingerprint readers for identification, replacing "fingerprint-gui". But I also read that the option was only available under Gnome 3.38 which is made for Ubuntu 20.10. And indeed I can't find the fingerprint setup in the parameters.

Did I miss something ?

**The specs of the machine :**

--> The computer is a *Dell XPS 13 2in1 2017*

--> The output of the command `fsusb` about the fingerprint sensor :

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0091 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7552 Touch Fingerprint Sensor`

Comment: Not all fingerprint readers are the same and some manufacturers are actively hostile to anything that is not Windows. What is the brand and model of computer that you’re using? Updating the question to include the device ID from `lsusb` may also offer the specificity required to answer this question 