# ThinkPad X390 Fingerprint login

Tags: 20.04, login, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

Apologies if this has been asked already or is easy to answer; I'm a new Ubuntu user. Ubuntu 20.04 allows me to turn on fingerprint login and register fingerprints in settings, but the reader does not work to log in. It prompts me to enter a password or swipe my fingerprint, but using the reader does nothing. The reader is not a "swipe" reader but just one where you rest your finger on it.

It seems odd to me that the reader works to register prints but not at login. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Took me 5 secs to find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231185/fingerprint-login-in-20-04). does it help?

Comment: Seems like I searched everywhere and didn't come across this. It works, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fingerprint login in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231185/fingerprint-login-in-20-04)